# Change Color of active tab font to black

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have simple table which sliding line under each tab.

Default color of font is `#aaaaaa` and for active tab i want font color to be black.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbNqYx

```
  <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">ONE</a></li><!--
 --><li class="two"><a href="#">TWO</a></li><!--
 --><li class="three"><a href="#">THREE</a></li><!--
 --><li class="four"><a href="#">FOUR</a></li>
    <hr />
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello Please add following JS:

```
$('.tab-nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(){  
   $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
   $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show(); 
   $(".tab-nav-wrapper ul li a").css('color','#aaaaaa');
   $(this).css('color','black');
});
```

Comment: It's better (in my opinion) to add/remove classes rather than CSS properties directly in code. Keep stylesheets for styles, and JS for code!

Answer (score 4):

You have to create an `.active{color:#000;}` class in the css and use this script to add/remove the active class:

```
.active{ color:#000; }
```

js:

```
$('.tab-nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(){ 
  $('.active').removeClass('active'); // <----remove the active class
  $(this).addClass('active'); // <----add the active class to clicked one.
  $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
 $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();  
});
```

#### [Updated codepen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obLYPy)

Comment: Beat me to it! Adding and removing classes like this is much better than setting css properties directly in JS, at least in my opinion.

Comment: absolutely! but seems some people don't like to toggle classes.

Comment: Ah well, it's better to be right than popular - at least with coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a class eg `current` when you activate the tab.

eg:

```
.current{
  color: #000000;
}
```

You can toggle the class on element selection:

```
$('.tab-nav-wrapper ul li a').click(function(){  
  $('.tab-nav-wrapper ul li a').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').hide();
 $('.tab-content-wrapper > div').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();  
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLKyzQ

Comment: It works by default it doesnt  select color for first tab. so i amm using this css `.tab-nav-wrapper > ul li:first-child a{color:#000 !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Add class `active` to default tab and move to active tab. Refer below code pend sample code on this scenario.

codepen.io/anon/pen/rxLWQw